# How to calculate a mosfet's maximum usable amperage based on a temperature

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, temperature

**With 3.3v at the gate & 12v at the drain, how many milliAmpere can i let flow trough [this](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irll3303.pdf) mosfet keeping it at a resonable temperature?**

and

**What is a resonable temperature ?**

40,60,80 or more °C

---

I just salvaged 3
[IRLL3303](http://www.irf.com/product-info/datasheets/data/irll3303.pdf) n-type mosfets. And a friend asked me if i could make him a rgb led lamp (for free). I'm trying to figrue out how many amperes i could let flow trough those mosfets but also keeping a low temperature.

1. i'm using a 3.3v mcu.
2. the volatage for the led strips is 12v.
3. everything should kept at a resonable temperature even in summer (max 37°C room temp).

*I tried different calculations from various sites but i always get different values and most of the time i can't find all the variables needed in the datasheet.*

I linked the datasheet but here is the important stuff:

> RDS(on) 0.045Ω (VGS = 4.5V, ID = 2.3A) **but i use 3.3v on the gate.**
>
> Power Dissipation (PCB Mount) 1.0 W
>
> Linear Derating Factor (PCB Mount) 8.3 mW/°C
>
> Junction and Storage Temperature Range -55 to + 150 °C
>
> Junction-to-Amb. (PCB Mount, steady state) normal=93°C/W max=120°C/W

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the data sheet Fig. 2, you can see a curve at different VGS values. Using the lowest curve (3.0 V), you can see it crosses 2 A at 0.2 V (it's a log-log scale). Therefore the on-resistance is 0.2/2 = 0.1 ohm. This is at +150 C, which is also the maximum allowed junction temperature (this is quite hot and would burn your finger if you touched it). Note that this is actually a typical plot, not a guaranteed worst case value, but in practice FETs are within 20 % of this value. Therefore let's assume 0.12 ohm.

If you don't have a real heatsink, it might be reasonable to assume a thermal resistance of 100 deg/W (with it mounted on a large sheet of metal, it might be 30 deg/W or less). Assuming an ambient of 60 deg (also very warm), and allowing up to 150 C junction, you can have a temperature rise of 150-60 = 90 deg. At 100 deg/W, this allows 90/100 = 0.9 W dissipation.

Using P = I^2*R, and 0.12 ohm gives a current of sqrt(0.9/0.12), or just over 2 A.

The 12 V LED strip value doesn't directly matter (as long as the FET's max VDS rating exceeds this which it does).

In cases like this, it's always better to be on the safe side and round calculations to the 'safe' side.

Comment: So the mosfet works at 3.3v?@Spehro Pefhany says it won't turn on.And if i can dissipate 0.9W, 0.9W/12V=75mA or "just over 2A"?@Spehro Pefhany says 350mA. now i'm confused

Comment: The plotted curves are typical rather than worst-case. So you might get this but it's not guaranteed : worst case will be closer to Spehro's answer. If you're making one, just measure Rds yourself at 3.3v, and decide...

Comment: @Brian Drummond measure the ohm resistance with my cheap multimeter between drain and source while i apply i 3.3v high on gate? then i get some milliohm as output. then sqrt(.9/output) ? that gives me the amperes. this would be at 150°C in the wors case?

Comment: what about "MOSFET is not guaranteed to switch 'on'" like @Spehro Pefhany said. true or not? btw thx for the math explaination (+1) even if not everything is clear.350mA vs 2000mA is a big difference.

Comment: Yes, it is not 'guaranteed' to switch on (in fact in the data sheet, I can only find a minimum VTH (1.0 V) -- no upper limit is specified.
In practice, I expect it would work just fine in this application at 3.3 V. I wouldn't go into high volume production with a FET that has data sheets this sloppy.

Comment: To concretize my 2 questions , if the mosfet turns on at that high voltage (3.3v), you say,  it could handle 2A at just under 150°C?

Comment: Yes -- the FET will conduct well enough to carry 2 A, and the power dissipated will be manageable.

Comment: i don't see anything in the datasheet that conducts to the conclusion that this mosfet should not turn on..., if you look at the  fig. 4 in the datasheet the test it at 10v Drain->Source , with voltages from 3v to  5.5v . and at 3.25v it states that 5Ampere could flow trough...

Answer (score 3):

This particular MOSFET is not guaranteed to switch 'on' very well with 3.3V on the gate. Suggest if your time is free put a bit less than 3.3V on the gate and measure Rds(on) for each part. Multiply that number by 1.5 and use that number for the 'hot' Rds(on), since it increases with temperature. Or just buy some better logic-level gate MOSFETs.

You will also need to estimate the worst-case temperature inside your enclosure and pick a maximum junction temperature to operate at, and decide whether you are using the minimum recommended footprint or something better.

For example if using the minimum recommended footprint and you want maximum junction temperature of 120 degrees C with a maximum ambient of  70 degrees C, then you can allow 50 degrees C rise. That's about 400mW allowable dissipation so if you are hoping to get 700mA you must have a cold Rds(on) with (say) 3.1V Vgs of about 0.54 ohm. It has a chance at that level, and a better chance at 350mA.

Comment: "put a bit less than 3.3V on the gate" with a resistor voltage divider (3v 2v)?? sorry but i'm not an electronical engineer, all this math is new and so some parts of your answer are not very clear for me. the max room temperature is 37°Celsius. I will use standard electronics enclosure (small, not ventilated).So your saying that 120°C is a resonable temperature?Where do i see in the datasheet that it won't turn on at 3.3v?

Comment: also if you could maybe explain the calculation you did so i don't have to ask everytime.

Comment: if you want i can draw the ciruit i'm planning to use.

Comment: btw.. i only have a cheap multimeter to measure. So i need to base everithing on theory in conjuction with the information i have in the datasheet. And i love to learn new stuff

Comment: @jp314 says worst case at 150°C it could handle 2000mA. 350mA vs 2000mA is a big difference.Even 700mA vs 350mA is. That said it's better i start with a 5cm led strip (45-50mA x channel), touching the mosfet , and over time add more strips until it gets hot. As i don't want to break the mosfet but learn more about electronics you could at least explain why this logic level mosfet should not turn on.

Comment: i don't see anything in the datasheet that conducts to the conclusion that this mosfet should not turn on..., if you look at the fig. 4 in the datasheet they test it at 10v Drain->Source , with voltages from 3v to 5.5v . and at 3.25v it states that 5Ampere could flow trough..

Comment: @cocco Yes, the operative word is "could". Or could not. It's a typical curve, not guaranteed. This is **not** a proper way to design things, but I did explain how to test if you want to spend your time that way.

Comment: "This is not a proper way to design things"...like i said i salvaged them, i'm not an electronical engineer & if you have any better solution than a logic level mosfet to control a 12v led strip from a 3.3v pin let me know. Actually i'm trying to find a nice logic level mosfet for 12v led strips controlled from 3.3v - 5v. I never found a perfect mosfet. I used darlington array's like uln2803 but they sink only real 200mA @ 12v per channel. mosfets are the only way i know to control high current and high voltage from 3.3v (pwm).

Comment: btw from what i learned until now (properly saturate the mosfet looking at the Vgs) the graph suggests i need at least 3.4v to fully saturate that mosfet... i just don't understand it.

Comment: An analogy. If I put you in a sealed room with some oxygen bottles, 3.4 bottles *might* be enough for you to survive a day but you might suffer some ill effects. 10 *will* be enough for you to survive and do some tasks. You can choose which is better.

Comment: it's a led lamp. A relatively low pwm frequency. Even if it looses -some pulses human eyes should not notice that. btw all this vague answers bring me to nothing. i'm trying to learn. Why should it not turn on?  is this mosfet made to be controlled from 1v? but then it's not even saturated... thats even wors. let's say 3v .what works on 3v? . i salvaged it from a pc motherboard with 3.3v regulators near it. I would be really happy if you'd tell me the problem of because it could or should not turn on.

Comment: It may turn on well enough you won't notice. It may not. There is no guarantee. They vary from unit to unit. If you're lucky it will work okay enough for you. If you test it you can find out. I know it's nothing critical.

Comment: you seem to be a intelligent person, and like electronics, i'm the ignorant in this case, but "this could not turn on", "this is not a proper way to design things" "oxigen bottles" those answers don't help me nor the other ppl who read this and know the same amount of electronics i know.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. A lot of people seem to be confused by 'typical' vs. 'guaranteed'. Analogies help some folks, but not others. An investment instrument has a guaranteed return of 1% P.A. but the sales person tells you it returned 4% the last 3 years. One is guaranteed, the other is typical.

Comment: i'm really only trying to learn and do things properly. your answer started good.. but this "is not guaranteed to switch 'on' " makes me crazy ... i was about to be proud of me for almost understanding mosfets. now i'm broken again. what happens ? does it lose "pulses" how could i find this usefull info in future datasheets? i look at the Vgs... and try to saturate it loking at the graph. but less voltage , why less voltage ... ?? is the response higher with less resistance?

Comment: It may have too much voltage drop with the load. That's all. So it gets hotter than it should and the LEDs will be dimmer than they should be. It's not complicated. 4.5V is 'on' for sure. 1V is almost off for sure. Anywhere in between is not for sure.

Comment: oh ok thx. now everything is clear... yeah ... i made a led lamp with npn transistors. then as the mcu has it's own voltage regulator i just let in a little more voltage. but thats in the 1-2v range. mosfets voltage drop should be much lower. i can increase the voltage when the circuit is finished. Another thing is that those cheap led strips are already desgned bad and so they are not nearly as bright as they should. ..

Comment: so basically some very low logic level mosfets if the vgs is to high drop alot of current and so also get hotter. if you mind ... i just read a datasheet of irl mosfets logic level .... where vgs min is 1.2v and max is 2.3v does that mean that if i have more than 2.3v i have the same problem? hot and high voltage drop? or it does not turn on

Comment: Vgs high is *not* a problem (unless you reach the maximum which is usually 6-20V). Even the 2.5V drive ones turn on a tiny bit better with more voltage. They don't draw any gate current to speak of, so it's all good. The MOSFET might cost a bit more though.

Comment: i'm like you when it comes to programming , it needs to be perfect. Electronics is new for me.. so even if i would , without an oscilloscope i can't create perfect circuits. So if it turns on i'm already happy... i just don't wanna burn down the house. thank you for your patience! ;)

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/Zef3zwh.jpg works like a charm ;) it starts to get warm (30-35°) with 120cm led strip 12v @ 30 leds * meter . tested at 5v mostly also with 3v ... no niticable difference. that should be around 660mA per channel. but in reallity it's prolly a little less.   i can measure only up to 200mA. soldering this tiny things is a mess...;)

Comment: "put a bit less than 3.3V on the gate and measure Rds(on) for each part. Multiply that number by 1.5 and use that number for the 'hot' Rds(on), since it increases with temperature" -- this isn't precisely true for FETs that are biased only a little bit (perhaps less than 1 V) above threshold voltage. Under that bias condition, the negative temperature coefficient of the threshold voltage (about -2 mV/deg. C) has a stronger influence than the mobility degradation with temperature, resulting in a net effect of RDSON IMPROVING with temperature.